# Dynamically choose driver type in Appium in order to write 'hybrid' tests

Tags: java, appium

I use Appium with Java to automate tests for mobile applications. It is clear that when I want to write tests for Android I use `AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = [..]` and for iOS I need to use `IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver = [..]` though with this approach I'd need to write same tests twice for iOS and Android. Is there a way that I could choose type of Appium Driver dynamically based on i.e. some kind of variable to choose between `AndroidDriver` and `iOSDriver`? I tried:

```
if(platform == "Android"){
    //returns AndroidDriver
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = COMMON.startAndroid(name, id, platform, version);
} else {
    //returns IOSDriver
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = COMMON.startIOS(name, id, platform, version);
}
```

but below in Test Eclipse points out that with this approach `driver` is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those drivers extend `WebDriver` interface (via inheritance). You can define driver from this type. It is also [OOP encapsulation concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

```
WebDriver driver;
if(platform.equals("Android")){
    driver = COMMON.startAndroid(name, id, platform, version);
} else {
    driver = COMMON.startIOS(name, id, platform, version);
}
```

Comment: Where is `platform` coming from?

Comment: @pnizzle from the OP question?

Comment: @pnizzle I'm guessing it's a value he/she reads from a configuration file to know the environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AppiumController {


public static OS executionOS = OS.ANDROID;
public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

public enum OS {
    ANDROID,
    IOS,
    MOBILEBROWER_IOS,
    MOBILEBROWER_ANDROID
}

public void start() {

    if (driver != null) {
        return;
    }

    switch(executionOS){
    case ANDROID: 
        // set android caps
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    case IOS:
        // set ios caps
        driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    case MOBILEBROWER_IOS:
        // set ios browser caps
        driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    case MOBILEBROWER_ANDROID:
        // set android browser caps
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
}

}
```